# Extracting XML that matches starting and ending patterns

Tags: xml, regex, sed

I am using sed to extract parts of an XML I am interested in:

```
sed '/<car car_id="BMW" year="1999"/,/</car>/p' input
```

So what I really would like to get back is:

```
<car car_id="BMW" year="1999" color="blue> ... </car>
```

Instead I get back a bunch of other car elements.

Comment: sed is not a good tool to parse XML. Try xpath instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `-n` option to prevent other lines from being printed and the selected lines from being double printed.

```
sed -n '/<car car_id="BMW" year="1999"/,/</car>/p' input
```

But there are better tools for manipulating XML (as **Steven** said).